# Combining multiple filters with %ilike%

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I'm working on matching last names between two tables. However, there are some variations that I have to take into account. For instance, I found that "Smith" in db1 can potentially have other forms in db2:

> Smith, Smith-Whatever, Smith Jr., Smith Sr., Smith III (any Roman numeral)

Lower/uppercase is also an issue.

I'm trying to implement this logic in dplyr. I found the %ilike% operator in `data.table`, which seems to work kind of like the SQL equivalent. I can use it like this:

```
match <- db2 %>% 
dplyr::filter(last_name %ilike% "^smith$" | last_name %ilike% "^smith-" | last_name %ilike% "^smith .r" | last_name %ilike% "^smith [ivx]")
```

Of course the strings wouldn't be hardcoded but rather obtained by iterating through db1. Either way, this is unwieldy.

Hence my question:

Is there a way to combine the functionality of %ilike% with something like %in% - by specifying a vector of regexes the 'ilikes' of which I would match against? Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: Your statement *"matching last names between two tables"* suggests a merge/join operation, in which case look into `fuzzyjoin::regex_*_join`.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks. However I'm looking at a situation where one row might (and usually will) have several matches, which I'd like to either duplicate or have the ids concatenated in one row. 

I also need to match (fuzzily) by first name and address in addition to last name.

Is that possible with the package you mention?

Comment: Most likely, yes. Please expand your question to include sample data (*both* tables) and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the pattern with `|`. You may use `grepl` (or `str_detect` if you are using `stringr`).

```
library(dplyr)

db2 %>% filter(grepl("smith( .r|-| [ivx]|.*)", last_name, ignore.case = TRUE))

#       last_name
#1          Smith
#2 Smith-Whatever
#3      Smith Jr.
#4      Smith Sr.
#5      Smith III
```

If you want to construct the pattern dynamically you can do -

```
pat <- c('smith', 'smith-', 'smith .r', 'smith [ivx]')

db2 %>%  dplyr::filter(grepl(paste0(pat, collapse = "|"), last_name, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

Also, would it be enough to `filter` rows that have only 'smith' in them ?

```
db2 %>%  filter(grepl('smith', last_name, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason I don't just filter for 'smith' is to avoid similar non-matches like 'smithers' or 'blacksmith'

Comment: You can add word boundaries (`\\b`) to avoid such matches. `db2 %>%  filter(grepl('\\bsmith\\b', last_name, ignore.case = TRUE))` @SpineFeast

Answer (score 1):

Using RonakShah's `pat` and my `db2` below, ...

### Filter

You might try an `any` operator to iterate through each pattern:

```r
db2 %>%
  filter(rowSums(sapply(pat, grepl, name)) > 0)
#              name
# 1           smith
# 2 smith-something
```

And since `data.table::%ilike%` and `data.table::%like%` are really using `grepl` under the hood, this is about the same thing.

### Merge/join

If your patterns are in a new frame, you can join them in with:

```r
patdf <- data.frame(ptn = pat, num = seq_along(pat))
patdf
#           ptn num
# 1       smith   1
# 2      smith-   2
# 3    smith .r   3
# 4 smith [ivx]   4

fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(db2, patdf, by = c("name" = "ptn"))
#              name    ptn num
# 1           smith  smith   1
# 2           jones   <NA>  NA
# 3          hubert   <NA>  NA
# 4 smith-something  smith   1
# 5 smith-something smith-   2
```

Granted, this is multiplying rows, since it matches multiple times. This can be reduced. Let's assume your original data has a unique `id` field:

```r
db2$id <- 10L + seq_len(nrow(db2))
fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(db2, patdf, by = c("name" = "ptn")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(ptn)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice_min(num) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   name               id ptn     num
#   <chr>           <int> <chr> <int>
# 1 smith              11 smith     1
# 2 smith-something    14 smith     1
```

---

Data

```r
db2 <- structure(list(name = c("smith", "jones", "hubert", "smith-something")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks. Basically, I have two db's -- both have last name, first name, address columns, as well as unique ids. Db1 has 40k records, db2 has 6mil. Atm, I'm simply iterating through db1 rows, matching by last name first (up to those small variations), then first name (again with variations), then address (fuzzy). My output is a db with the db1 id + all matching db2 ids (graded: potential, likely, exact - depending on how well the address fields match). Perhaps there is a more intelligent way of doing this. I might have to make a separate question and link this one.